# unable to log in to apache superset

Tags: docker, apache-superset

I installed Apache superset through docker but I cannot make the login. I am trying use admin/admin credentials but it returns invalid login.
I am trying to use some information found here, like `docker-compose exec superset bash -c 'export FLASK_APP=superset && flask fab create-admin'` but I got the error `flask_appbuilder.security.sqla.manager:Error adding new user to database. (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) relation "ab_user_role" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO ab_user_role (id, user_id, role_id) VALUES (next...`.

I am beginner in use docker and Apache superset, could someone help me to understand what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Apparently, you need to create the db. Run this first:

```
docker-compose run --rm -e FLASK_APP=superset superset flask fab create-db
```